# bash Syntax Madness - How to get third until last command line argument into an array

Tags: arrays, bash, command-line-arguments

I have it working but cannot believe that the syntax should be that mad. All I want to do is to get the all arguments beginning with the third into an array.

E.g.

```
script.sh foo bar value1 value2 value3
```

Should give me an array containing value1, value2, and value3. This array is the used to provide the parameters in a new function:

```
./runpy /dsnormalize.py "${values[@]}"
```

This works:

```
args=( "$@" )
length=$((${#args[@]}-2))
values=(${args[@]:$length:2})
```

Please tell me this is not the correct way. I usually ended up with a string containing all values.

How does bash handle strings and integers anyway?
And is the difference between ${} and $()?

Thanks for your help,
Karsten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
args_from_third=("{@:3}")
```

It's not necessary to insert the length, because the default is "the rest of the arguments".

It's certainly true that `bash` parentheses are complicated. The two I use here:

```
VARIABLE=(...)
```

This creates an array called `VARIABLE`, whose values are the whitespace delimited elements of the string `...`.

```
"${@:start:length}"
```

This expands to `length` arguments starting at argument `start`; if `length` is omitted, it uses all the rest of the arguments. The arguments are separated by space characters. Because the expression is quoted, each argument (but not the space delimiters) is treated as though it were quoted.

`${...}` covers a lot of possibilities, including substring, search-and-replace and case-changing. Look at the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for details.

Comment: This did not work. I should have added that I use the parameters to call a different function,. I updated my post.

Comment: @Karsten: In that case, you don't need the array. Just `./runpy /dsnormalize.py "${@:3}"`. If you tried that and it didn't meet your expectations, you'll have to be more precise than "it didn't work". (Didn't you mean `./dsnormalize.py`, by the way?)

Comment: Hi, "${@:3}" worked. Thanks! How would I save this in a variable at the beginning and the use this variable: normalize.py "${columns[@]}"?

Comment: @Karsten: As in my answer, `columns=("${@:3}")`. What made you think that was incorrect?

Comment: That didn't work. However, I think I passed it incorrectly. How would I pass columns to normalize?

Comment: @Karsten: as you had it. `"${columns[@]}"`. Can you more describe precisely what you did, what the result or error was, and how it differs from what you expected? (Edit your question or use a pastebin)

Comment: Using `"{@:3}"` each time works. I could not get it to work with a variable.

Comment: @Karsten I still don't know what you tried *exactly* and consequently I don't know what you mean by "didn't work". There is no way to pass an array to a bash function, other than by expanding it into the positional parameters, so if you tried something like `./dsnormalize $columns` then it wouldn't do what you want. If you want to expand a subsequence of an array, you need to use the syntax `"${columns[@]:2}"` (remember, unlike `$@`, array indices start at 0). If none of those fit your issue, *please ask a more precise question*.

Comment: I have a bash script calling other programs, e.g. dsnormalize. dsnormalize expects column names as parameters. I would like to pass theses names to my bash script: `process.sh file_name another_param c_name_1 ... c_name_n`. I need the array of names a few times. Thus I would like to save it in a variable. However, I have no clue how to pass the names as parameters to another program. All proposed solutions end up that dsnormalize script sees one parameter `"column_name_1 ... column_name_2"` instead of `"column_name_1" ... "column_name_n"` which I get if I pass `"{@:3}"` to dsnormalize directly

Comment: @Karsten: `columns=("${@:3}"); ./dsnormalize "${columns[@]}"` will do just that. But you claim in an earlier comment to have been unsatisfied with that, without having specified why. (On the other hand, if that's all you need to do, using the extra array variable is not very useful.)

Comment: `columns=("${@:3}"); ./dsnormalize "${columns[@]}"` seemed to pass just to pass `"column_name_1 ... cloumn_name_n"` instead of `"column_name_1" ... "column_name_n"`. So one string instead of an array. I will check that again. Thanks for your extensive help anyways!

Answer (score 4):

A much easier way to do this is by using `shift` to remove the fixed arguments.

```
first_arg=$1
second_arg=$2
shift 2
the_rest=("$@")
```

And:

> How does bash handle strings and integers anyway? And is the difference between `${}` and `$()`?

`${}` is used to get a variable's value. The curly brackets are optional if you're just writing `$foo`, but they're required for anything more complicated, such as accessing elements of an array.

`$()` captures the output of a command, similar to backticks. This is different from `$(( ))`, which is what you're using.

`$(( ))` evaluates an arithmetic expression. It lets you do basic integer and boolean operations.

Comment: +1 A little longer than using `${@:3}`, but POSIX-compatible (which, on second thought, is irrelevant since arrays are not POSIX).